# Problemas con busquedas mes anterios en datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema raro en un script de filtrar por fechas los registros, resulta que cuando filtro del 01/02/2024 me muestra todos los registros de esa fecha, pero cuando filtro por ejemplo del 01/01/2024 a 30/01/2024 me mustra un error de datatable:
***DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Incorrect column count. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/18***
y no me muestra ningun registro.

Les dejo el codigo:

HTML

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="de" required>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="hasta" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required>
    <script>
  function validarFechas() {
    var fechaDe = strtotime(document.getElementsByName("de")[0].value);
    var fechaHasta = strtotime(document.getElementsByName("hasta")[0].value) + 86399; // Suma 23 horas, 59 minutos y 59 segundos al timestamp de la fecha hasta

    if (fechaDe > fechaHasta) {
    Swal.fire({
    text: "¡La fecha de inicio no puede ser mayor que la fecha de fin!",
    showConfirmButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
})
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Scrit que trae los registros y llena la tabla:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formulario-busqueda").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "buscar.php",
            data: formData,
            success: function(result) {
                $("#resultado-busqueda").html(result);
                $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                    ],
                    order: [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                    language: {
                        url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json'
                    },
                    lengthChange: true // Añade el select con los números de páginas
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error en la búsqueda.");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Pagina buscar.php

```
<link href="datatable/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="datatable/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="datatable/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
    <link href="datatable/css/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>-->


<?php

    include('../conectar.ini.php');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/*$de = isset($_POST['de']) ? $_POST['de'] : '';
$hasta = isset($_POST['hasta']) ? $_POST['hasta'] : '';*/
$de = isset($_POST['de']) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['de'])) : '';
$hasta = isset($_POST['hasta']) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['hasta'])) : '';


$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, dni, area, tel, mail, ubi_actual, ubi_soli, estado, fecha ";
$sql .= " FROM lista_espera";
$sql .= " WHERE 1=1"; // Esta línea agrega una condición verdadera para empezar la cláusula WHERE

if ($de != '') {
    $sql .= " AND fecha >= '$de'";
}
if ($hasta != '') {
    $sql .= " AND fecha <= '$hasta'";
}

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$resultado) {
    printf("Error en la consulta SQL: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}

?>
<form method='post' id="formulario" action='actualizar-estado-filtro.php'>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%"><input type="checkbox" id="todos"></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Apellido y nombre:</th>
                <th>D.N.I:</th>
                <th>Numero del telefono</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Ubicación Actual</th>
                <th>Ubicación Solicitada</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $encontrado = false; // Variable de bandera para indicar si se ha encontrado algún resultado
            while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                $encontrado = true; // Se ha encontrado un resultado
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo "<input type='checkbox' name='usuarios[]' value='" . $fila['id'] . "' />" ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila['dni']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila["area"] . " " . $fila["tel"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila['mail']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila['ubi_actual']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila['ubi_soli']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        if ($fila["estado"] == 0) {
                            echo  "<a style='cursor: pointer' onclick='eliminarPersona(" . $fila['id'] . ")'><span class='badge rounded-pill bg-danger'>PENDIENTE</span></a>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<span class='badge rounded-pill bg-success'>PROCESADO</span>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fila['fecha'])); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }

            if (!$encontrado) {
                echo "<tr><td colspan='10'>No se encontraron resultados.</td></tr>";
            }
            ?>
            
<!--            <tr>
<th scope="row">
<input class="btn btn btn-success btn-sm" type='submit' id="exportar" name='exportar' value='Procesar Seleccionados'></th> 
</tr>-->

    
    
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input class="btn btn btn-success btn-sm" type='submit' id="exportar" name='exportar' value='Procesar Seleccionados'>
    </form> 

    <?php
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</div>

<script>
  let btn = document.getElementById('exportar');

  function submitForm(event) {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    let isChecked = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        isChecked = true;
        break; 
      }
    }

    if (!isChecked) {
      event.preventDefault(); 
      Swal.fire({
        html: `<h4>Debes seleccionar al menos una persona para poder procesarla</h4>`,
      });
    } else {
      let confirmacion = confirm("¿Desea seguro que deseas pasar a procesado todos los datos selecciondados?");
      if (!confirmacion) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
      }
    }
  }

  btn.addEventListener("click", submitForm);
</script>


<script>
let btn = document.getElementById('exportar');
function submitForm(elemento) {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
  let isChecked = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      isChecked = true;
    }
  }

  if (isChecked) {
      document.getElementById('formulario').submit();
     
  } else {
    Swal.fire({
    html: `<h4>Debes seleccionar al menos una persona para poder exportar a Excel</h4>`,
    });
    elemento.preventDefault();
  }
}
    btn.addEventListener("click", submitForm);
</script>


<script>
      function eliminarPersona(id) {
      Swal.fire({
          title: "¿Desea pasar a procesado?",
          text: "Recuerde que eso sera irreversible!",
          icon: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
          cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
          confirmButtonText: "¡Sí, procesar!",
          cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
         }).then((result) => {
          
          if (result.isConfirmed) { 
              Swal.fire(
                  "¡Eliminado!",
                  "pasasdo correctamente.",
                  "success"
              )
              window.location.href = "estado-filtro.php?id  =" + id;
          }
        });
        };
</script>

    
<script>
$('#todos').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
</script>

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>-->
    
        <script src="datatable/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable/js/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Y devolvió resultados el servidor?

Comment: si coloco una fecha del mes pasado no, no devuelve nada.

Comment: Me parece que tendrías que validar primeramente si el result del AJAX "tiene algo" antes de generar la tabla... De hecho, [ese enlace del error](http://datatables.net/tn/18) da pistas de cuándo aparece tal error de DataTable. Hablando mal y rápido: el servidor retornó "OK", pero sin resultados.

Comment: si, ese error ya lo vi en datatable y lo que dice es que no coincide los campos de la tabla con los campos del resultado, y no es asi porque cuando busco en mes actual si me muestra resultados, pero si busco un mes anterior no me mustra resultado y salta ese error. muy raro

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra@SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar todo el código del archivo `buscar.php`? Aparentemente que el problema esta en el resultado devuelvo por dicho script.

Comment: Ahi lo edite y puse todo el codigo de la pagina buscar. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hmmmm... ¿Qué sucede si quitás todo el _if_ de `if (!$encontrado)`? Me parece que va por ahí, porque estás definiendo una fila con una sola columna en lugar de 10 (y es por eso que aparece el error). En cuanto a los filtros de tu consulta: ¿tenés la certeza de que se debería devolver resultados en el rango de fecha que ingresaste?

Comment: De tener certeza si, deberia, abi pruebo quietando el if

Comment: ahi saque el if y lo mismo no me muestra ningun resultado, pero ya no me muestra el error de datatable. Es raro porque si busco en el mes de febrero si me muestra resultado, pero si busco mes anterior no me muestra nada y veo en la base que si hay registros.

Comment: Por lo menos el problema de DataTable ya se resolvió: efectivamente no coincidía la cantidad de columnas de la tabla con la cantidad de cabeceras :) Ahora: ¿probaste la misma consulta desde tu gestor de base de datos? ¿Depuraste qué consulta se está ejecutando en el servidor y con qué parámetros?

Comment: ahi lo que hice fue borrar toda la base y empeza a cargar registros con diferentes fechas y ahora si me muestra las fechas que filro, si ve que habia algo mal en la base.